# the lazily-initialize type does not have a public parameter-less constructor

Tags: c#, lazy-initialization

I am trying to implement an [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xk-AKHUCdGc&index=5&list=PL6n9fhu94yhUbctIoxoVTrklN3LMwTCmd) in youtube, the tutor got it right but I got an error.
I already have a private constructor and I cannot have public constructor in my code.

```
private static int _InstanceCount = 0;

private SingletonDemo1()
{
    _InstanceCount++;
    Console.WriteLine("Instance Count: " + _InstanceCount.ToString());
}

private static readonly Lazy<SingletonDemo1> _Instance = new Lazy<SingletonDemo1>();

public static SingletonDemo1 Instance
{
    get
    {                               
        return _Instance.Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the example you need to manually initialize the object in the constructor of the Lazy just like in the demo video

```
private static readonly Lazy<SingletonDemo1> _Instance = new Lazy<SingletonDemo1>(() => new SingletonDemo1());
```

Note the factory function used.

Without it the code would try to use reflection to initialize the object but as you have already stated the constructor is private so it will fail. That is why you need to tell the `Lazy` how to create the instance when needed.

Comment: Is there a performance benefit to specifying initialization this way even if the default constructor __is__ public, since that would skip the reflection?